# How to get rid of the internet security virus (for free)

Tags: windows-7, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Not sure if this is the right place to as but here goes:

My sister got the virus on her laptop I've seen a few sites to that claim to remove the virus but ask to register with some software of their's is there any out there which are legit and I can get for free.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you can boot into Safe Mode without the "Internet Security" malware starting, I would try [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com) as a first-step.

If you can't boot into Safe Mode, or if the infection is still present in Safe Mode, I would recommend booting to and scanning with the [MS Standalone System Sweeper](http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper), followed by booting into the OS (or booting to a WinPE disc [Win7/Vista installation or Startup Repair discs, [Ultimate BootCD](http://www.ubcd4win.com/), etc]) and running [TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) to check for rootkits.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two nice options from Kaspersky: AVPTool and RescueCD
http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner

AVPTool contains their antivirus engine packed with latest definitions, it should clear everything up quite nicely.

Bonus:

- You can always just install a trial version of Symantec, ESET, McAffee or Kaspersky Antivirus, scan your system and delete it afterwards.
- If you want a free endpoint protection suite, try Avast: http://www.avast.com/ (But be warned - their protection is not quite up to par with industry leaders, such as McAffee, Kaspersky, ESET and Symantec)